# Place two frames together with relative width

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to place two frames together inside another frame but I can't done it with the layout managers.[image: Layout that I get]

The frames are imported from ttk, gray area is the result of border. My target is, the first image fill all gray area on the left, and the second fill the gray area on right. Eventually I'm gonna change the second picture by another widget.
My code is:

```
    class Window(Frame):
        def __init__(self, master, *args):
            super().__init__(master, *args)
            self.principal_frame = Frame(self.master)
            self.principal_frame.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')
            self.master.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.master.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
            self.widgets()

        def tactical_window(self):
            self.pages.select([self.third_frame])

        def widgets(self):
            self.image_pitch = PhotoImage(file=...)
            self.pages = ttk.Notebook(self.principal_frame)
            self.pages.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
            self.third_frame = Frame(self.pages, bg='white')
            self.third_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
            self.pages.add(self.third_frame)

            # Third Frame
            self.frame_tactic_pitch = ttk.Frame(self.third_frame, borderwidth=2)
            self.frame_player_list = ttk.Frame(self.third_frame, borderwidth=3)
            self.frame_pitch_tactic.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, pady=2, padx=2)
            self.frame_players_tactic.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=False, fill=tk.Y, pady=2, padx=2)
            
            # Pitch
            self.canvas_pitch = tk.Canvas(self.frame_tactic_pitch)
            self.canvas_pitch.pack()
            self.canvas_pitch.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image_pitch, anchor='nw')
            self.canvas_pitch1 = tk.Canvas(self.frame_player_list)
            self.canvas_pitch1.pack()
            self.canvas_pitch1.create_image(0, 0, image=self.image_pitch, anchor='nw')
            
            ...
```

I'm trying `self.frame_tactic_pitch` use ≈75% of `self.third_frame` and `self.frame_player_list` the remaining.

And the widget canvas uses the total of `self.frame_tactic_pitch` but that the image fits fairly, it doesn't matter if enlarging the window deforms the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to achieve what you want is to create a uniform group, by giving both columns the same value for the `uniform` option. Then, give each column a proportional weight. In your case it's 3 and 1. `grid` will then maintain the sizes in strict proportion to the weight.

From the official grid documentation:

> The -uniform option, when a non-empty value is supplied, places the column in a uniform group with other columns that have the same value for -uniform. The space for columns belonging to a uniform group is allocated so that their sizes are always in strict proportion to their -weight values.

It looks something like the following example. This example puts the two frames in the root window, but the technique will work just as well by putting the frames in another frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x200")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="raised")
f2 = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="raised")

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=3, uniform="group1")
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="group1")

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
f2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It works in space distribution , but the canvas image doesn't fill all the frame space.

Comment: @VictorCaicedo: There's nothing in this solution that will prevent a canvas or any other widgets from filling the space inside either frame. You'll have to write code to resize the image, that won't happen automatically. There are questions on this site with answers that show how to do that.